# Will AspNetCore.SignalR work with old client library?

Tags: asp.net-core, uwp, signalr

I want to update my aspnet app to .net core and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR`.

Do I have to update also client apps (UWP, Xamarin) to use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` or it is possible to continue to use `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client`.

The problem is that I cannot update my client apps to .NET Standard 2.0 so easily.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to update also client apps (UWP, Xamarin) to use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client or it is possible to continue to use Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client

By testing on my side, if the server side installed with [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Gray.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server/) package, and at the same time client side installed with [`Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/) package, client can connect to server and work well. So that it seems like it is possible to continue using `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client` without code changing to communicate with server that using `AspNetCore.SignalR`.

The client I'm using for testing is from [this sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/How-to-create-a-real-time-5626562d) that with `AspNet.SignalR.Client` package referenced and the server side with `AspNetCore` referenced is from [here](https://github.com/FredHan001/SignaIRCoreDemo). You can also have a testing.

Additionally, I didn't find `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` package in Nuget currently, it seems like it it [not available](https://libraries.io/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) for your client side.

Comment: The sample you refer to uses a package called Gray.Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server. As far as I know, this is the old version of SignalR, wrongly renamed and released by someone random. So, yes, it will work with AspNet.SignalR.Client. 

That's not to claim that the new .NET Core release of SignalR couldn't be backward compatible. It could, but I doubt it.